# Headers changed in onBeforeSendHeaders are not sent

Tags: ajax, google-chrome-extension, http-headers

This is relevant to Chrome 72+ (working around updates introduced with https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/extension-content-script-fetches)

In my chrome extension's background script I need to set the Referer header. That is the code I use for that:

```
var extraInfoSpec = ['blocking', 'requestHeaders'];
if (chrome.webRequest.OnBeforeSendHeadersOptions.hasOwnProperty('EXTRA_HEADERS'))
  extraInfoSpec.push('extraHeaders');

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(function(details){
  var newRef = "http://referer.url/page";
  var gotRef = false;
  for(var n in details.requestHeaders){
      gotRef = details.requestHeaders[n].name.toLowerCase()=="referer";
      if(gotRef){
          details.requestHeaders[n].value = newRef;
          break;
      }
  }
  if(!gotRef){
      details.requestHeaders.push({name:"Referer",value:newRef});
  }
  return {requestHeaders:details.requestHeaders};
},{
  urls:["my_test_path_url"]
}, extraInfoSpec);
```

When I output the content of `details.requestHeaders` before returning it - it shows me the array of headers including `Referer`.

Later in `background.js` I make an ajax call to the `my_test_path_url` like this:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   headers: {"Authorization": `Bearer ${secretToken}`}, 
   url: requestURL,
   dataType: 'json',
   success: ...
```

Then I take a look at the Network console - and see that neither of the `extraHeaders` were added to the request.

To double-check, I added a listener for `onSendHeaders` (tried various configuration for extra params) and was never able to observe `Referer` header to be specified in `requestHeaders`.

The question is - how to ensure that `Referer` is passed with request? And possibly how to confirm in `onSendHeaders` that `Referer` is still intact?

--

Request headers as shown inside `onBeforeSendHeaders`:
[image]

Request headers as shown in Network inspector:
[image]

Comment: Assuming `my_test_path_url` is correct in the actual code, is it buggy in Chrome 73 or just 72? The latter had many unresolved bugs fixed in the former.

Comment: I am now on version 73. Haven't tested this code in 72.

Comment: The posted code seems fine and a very similar code works for me in Chrome 73.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Chrome 72, the following request headers are not provided and cannot be modified or removed without specifying 'extraHeaders' in opt_extraInfoSpec:

- Accept-Language
- Accept-Encoding
- Referer
- Cookie

so, you can use:

```
var extraInfoSpec = ['blocking', 'requestHeaders', 'extraHeaders'];
```